# Clean way of toggling elements with animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, animated

I need to toggle elements and animate them in & out. The toggle/animate have to be in different order which makes this tricky.

This is what I have now:

```
var isActive = false;

$("a.handle").click(function() {

if (isActive == false) { 
    $("div.element").show();
    $("div.element").toggleClass("fadeInRight fadeOutRight");
    isActive = true;
}
else {
    $("div.element").toggleClass("fadeInRight fadeOutRight");
    $("div.element").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() { $("div.element").hide(); } );
    isActive = false;
}

});
```

It works, but I feel there must be a more effective way to write this. Is there a way to do this without the `isActive` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `isActive` variable and work with jquery [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method. Something like this:

```
  $("a.handle").click(function() {

      if ($("div.element").hasClass("fadeInRight")) { // or  $("div.element").hasClass("fadeOutRight") based on your need...
          $("div.element").show();
         $("div.element").toggleClass("fadeInRight fadeOutRight");
      }
    else {
          $("div.element").toggleClass("fadeInRight fadeOutRight");
          $("div.element").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() { $("div.element").hide(); } );
         }           

     });
```

Comment: @Egregory: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just add a selector to your current selector $("a.handle"). Just add the :visible selector at the end $("a.handle:visible").

EDIT: Actually I for got to add this is if the element is not taking up any white space.

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)